# Remove wordpress sidebar completely

Tags: php, wordpress, sidebar

I would like to remove the right-hand sidebar from all pages. I have had limited success stopping it from displaying, but I also want the latest posts to fit across the area where the sidebar used to be. My theme is cyber chimps if you care, and I have tried live editing in Chrome, but that puts the content all over the place.
Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: You'll need to look in your theme's template files and remove it. Take a look in page.php, single.php, archive.php and date.php (if your theme has them) else it could be just index.php

Comment: Easy way, use css to hide it and 100% the main section, better way change the template and css. Or hire someone todo it for you as `editing in Chrome` seems like you have no idea how stuff works ;p

Comment: I'm editing it in Chrome to see what _could_ work, and then I'm also trying the css, and php etc

Comment: changed line containg
 $content_span = ( $wide_sidebar == 1 ) ? 'cyberchimps_class_span8' : 'cyberchimps_class_span9';

to

$content_span = ( $wide_sidebar == 1 ) ? 'cyberchimps_class_span8' : '';

Answer (score 1):

In your edit page screen, on the right hand side is a meta box titled 'Template'.  Click on that and see if there's any titled something like 'no sidebar'.

If there's not, as the comments above state, you'll either need to edit your themes files, or hire someone to do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

I just successfully removed the sidebar from my Single Page template on my website's theme.
To do it, just comment out the code that triggers the sidebar. I highly recommend that you do NOT delete the code, as deleted code from Wordpress is hard to recover without a cold install of the theme. The code I found looked something like this:

```
<?php if ( empty( $po_layout ) ) get_sidebar(); ?>
```

I commented it out like so:

```
<?php /* if ( empty( $po_layout ) ) get_sidebar(); */ ?>
```

The important thing to be on the lookout for is this:

```
get_sidebar();
```

The get_sidebar(); function is what builds the sidebar on your website.

Good luck!